# Batch metadata and text extraction of pdf files

Tags: pdf, batch, conversion, adobe-acrobat, metadata

I have a set of PDF files, all of which contain text. However, some of these files were somehow not created properly; the selectable text is not searchable or convertible to plain text (the resulting text file contains extended ascii characters). Some of the files have even more sneaky of a failure, in that exporting to txt results in only certain text (e.g. headings) being readable. Also, since these are technically 'text' PDFs, running OCR directly on them is not possible (an error is produced saying "This page contains renderable text.") I'm trying to pin down why this is happening and how the damaged PDFs can be fixed.

This is what I'd like to do as a batch process for each pdf file:

1. Extract the "PDF Producer" metadata tag
2. Convert the PDF to text
3. Convert the PDF to a TIFF
4. Run OCR on the resulting TIFF and export it to txt
5. Run a diff on the PDF->TXT text file vs the PDF->TIFF->OCR->TXT text file
6. Write the metadata tag and a boolean result of the txt diff to a csv file

I have adobe acrobat X Pro, a cygwin installation and a windows exiftool (from [here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)) to work with, and can access other tools if necessary.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can tackle this issue?